# How can I extract items from a list, between a starting and ending number?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I need to extract some items from the list, only those between 90 and 88, see the image for a better explanation. Does anyone have any solution like formulas? Or it could also be some VBA code. I've tried as formulas, but I haven't been successful[image]

Comment: This seems something very programmatic - you could iterate through, look for 90, and copy the cells after that 90 cell unless its an 88. Then you do it again but looking from the next cell. Something like a while loop in VBA - I have no idea on how to do it but I'm sure its fully possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your start is in D1 and end is in E1, put this formula in cell B2:

```
=AND(OR(A1=$D$1,B1),A2<>$E$1)
```

Then drag it down to the bottom of the list.

Then filter column A using column B as the include parameter. This formula goes in cell E3:

```
=FILTER($A$1:$A$15,$B$1:$B$15)
```

Adjust ranges appropriately.

[image]

Comment: Until it worked. But I added a number other than 88 in the last line and even so he considered it as true and pulled the numbers